# Text added to combo box is highlighted

Tags: c#

I have a method that appends or inserts characters to the text of either a combo box or textbox depending on what was last focused on. I am using buttons to pass in the character as a parameter, Using a keyboard or sendkeys is not an option. When my method appends or inserts characters into a textbox the result is as expected however when the same method is applied to a combobox the text of the combobox is highlighted. Obviously this is not the functionality im looking for and I believe this is stopping the autocomplete mode from working correctly.

Why is the combobox behaving differently than the textbox?

The code:

```
private void createText(string lowerCaseChar, string upperCaseChar)
{
    Control FocusedTextComboBox;
    switch (lastTextComboBoxFocused)
    {
        case 54:
            FocusedTextComboBox = SearchTextBox;
            break;
        case 4:
            FocusedTextComboBox = VendorComboBox;
            break;
        case 6:
            FocusedTextComboBox = SectionComboBox;
            break;
        case 5:
            FocusedTextComboBox = DeptComboBox;
            break;
        default:
            FocusedTextComboBox = SearchTextBox;
            break;
    }

    if (FocusedTextComboBox is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox FocusedTextBox = (TextBox)FocusedTextComboBox;

        int SelectionStartNumber = FocusedTextBox.SelectionStart;

        switch (shift)
        {
            case true:
                FocusedTextBox.Text = FocusedTextBox.Text.Insert(FocusedTextBox.SelectionStart, upperCaseChar);
                break;
            case false:
                FocusedTextComboBox.Text = FocusedTextComboBox.Text.Insert(FocusedTextBox.SelectionStart, lowerCaseChar);
                break;
        }
        FocusedTextBox.SelectionStart = SelectionStartNumber + 1;
        FocusedTextBox.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        ComboBox FocusedComboBox = (ComboBox)FocusedTextComboBox;

        if (FocusedComboBox.SelectionStart == 0 && FocusedComboBox.Text != "")
        {
            switch (shift)
            {
                case true:
                    FocusedComboBox.Text += upperCaseChar;
                    break;
                case false:
                    FocusedComboBox.Text += lowerCaseChar;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int SelectionStartNumber = FocusedComboBox.SelectionStart;

            switch (shift)
            {
                case true:
                    FocusedComboBox.Text = FocusedComboBox.Text.Insert(FocusedComboBox.SelectionStart, upperCaseChar);
                    break;
                case false:
                    FocusedTextComboBox.Text = FocusedTextComboBox.Text.Insert(FocusedComboBox.SelectionStart, lowerCaseChar);
                    break;
            }
            FocusedComboBox.SelectionStart = SelectionStartNumber + 1;
        }
        FocusedComboBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setting focus back to the combobox is highlighting the text, move FousedCombox.Focus() to before assigning text to combobox.